# Adding 2 rows with 0s at the start and end of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, row

I have a pandas Dataframe named dataframe.
I want to add two rows at the start and end of the data frame with 0s.

```
#create DataFrame
df_x = pd.DataFrame({'logvalue': ['20', '20.5', '18.5', '2', '10'],
                     'ID': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']})
```

Output should look like below.

| logvalue | ID | violatedInstances |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 20 | 1 | 0 |
| 20.5 | 2 | 1 |
| 18.5 | 3 | 0 |
| 2 | 4 | 1 |
| 10 | 5 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |

The output should rearrange the indexes of the dataframe as well.
How can I do this in pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

- First create a new dataframe (`df_y`) that contains the zero'd row
- Use the `concat` function to join this dataframe with the original
- Use the `reset_index(drop=True)` function to reset the index.

#### Code:

```
df_x = pd.DataFrame({ 'logvalue': [20.0, 20.5, 18.5, 2.0, 10.0, 0.0],
                    'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0],
                    'violatedInstances': [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]})

# Extract the column names from the original dataframe
column_names = df_x.columns
number_of_columns = len(column_names)
row_of_zeros = [0]*number_of_columns

# Create a new dataframe that has a row of zeros
df_y = pd.DataFrame([row_of_zeros], columns=column_names)

# Join the dataframes together
output = pd.concat([df_y, df_x, df_y]).reset_index(drop=True)

print(output)
```

#### Output:

```
   logvalue  ID  violatedInstances
0       0.0   0                  0
1      20.0   1                  0
2      20.5   2                  1
3      18.5   3                  0
4       2.0   4                  1
5      10.0   5                  1
6       0.0   0                  0
7       0.0   0                  0
```

Comment: I tried this. But my dataframe have so many columns. So I need not use the column names. I'm trying to avoid that

Comment: Ok - have updated so that it doesn't matter if you have 1000 columns, it should still work without any additional effort.

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

```
df_x = pd.DataFrame({'logvalue': ['20', '20.5', '18.5', '2', '10'],
                     'ID': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']})
```

`df_x`

```
    logvalue    ID
0   20          1
1   20.5        2
2   18.5        3
3   2           4
4   10          5
```

---

**Code**

use `reindex` with `fill_value`

```
idx = ['start'] + df_x.index.tolist() + ['end']
df_x.reindex(idx, fill_value=0).reset_index(drop=True)
```

result:

```
    logvalue    ID
0   0           0
1   20          1
2   20.5        2
3   18.5        3
4   2           4
5   10          5
6   0           0
```

['start'] and ['end'] of `idx` variable : any label that is not in index of df_x.